# Using Leaderboard scores for game logic

Tags: iphone, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

I don't see anything in the rules about this...however the guide for Gamekit says you can retrieve leaderboard scores for showing them, but I was wondering if I could use them in the process of match making, to match players better? Does anyone know of an example where this is done or have done it themselves? I'm not interested in how to implement it, just if its allowed to use the Leader board data for things over than displaying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the data for whatever you want.

The documentation for GKLeaderboard makes frequent mention of "use or display".
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13

Also there is no mention that this is not allowed in the App Store Review Guidelines.
https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html
(Developer login required)

Answer (score -1):

hey you use below link for use Gamekit hope it help you:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5509/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-2

Comment: Hey this is a good tutorial, but sadly it doesn't answer my question. I'm just curious if I can use leader board scores in my game logic and not only for displaying.